# Show activity over alert dialog builder in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to show a WebView over an AlertDialog.Builder in Android and having trouble doing that. I understand that if shown, a dialog needs to be closed in order to regain focus of what's behind but if the situation is that you want to show a webview above the dialog, what are the options? Calling the webview before calling the dialog does not solve this.

Is this approach that bad? thank you.

This is the method to create the dialog

```
public static void showExitPopup(final Context context) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle("Exit?");
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
        builder.setMessage("\nYou really want to exit?\n")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();

                            }
                        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        builder.show();

    }
```

This is the webview:

```
public static WebView create(final Context context) {

        // Create WebView Instance
        WebView webView = new WebView(context);

        // Set WebView Optimize;
        webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        webView.setFocusable(true);
        webView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        webView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        // Init WebSettings
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        return webView;

    }
```

And then in a different method i am creating the webview and loading a specific url and before that loading the dialog.

Comment: can you please post code ?

Comment: i have edited the initial post with code. thank you